# What is the difference between 'open' and 'public' in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, keyword, public

I am new to Kotlin and I am confused between `open` and `public` keywords. Could anyone please tell me the difference between those keywords?

Comment: Read this article if you want more clarification on "open" keyword in Kotlin
https://www.android4dev.com/what-is-open-class-in-android-kotlin/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The `open` keyword means “open for extension“ - i.e. it's possible to create *subclasses* of an `open` class:

> The `open` annotation on a **class** is the opposite of Java's `final`: it allows others to inherit from this class. By *default*, all classes in Kotlin are `final`, which corresponds to **Effective Java, Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it**.

You also need to be explicit about methods you want to make overridable, also marked with `open`:

```
open class Base {
    open fun v() {}
    fun nv() {}
}
```

The `public` keyword acts as a [visibility modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html) that can be applied on classes, functions, member functions, etc. If a top-level class or function is `public`, it means it can be used from other files, including from other modules. Note that `public` is the default if nothing else is specified explicitly:

> If you do not specify any visibility modifier, `public` is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible everywhere

Comment: What is the meaning of the phrase "your declarations will be visible everywhere"?

Comment: That’s a quote from the docs, any class will have access and can create an instance: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Comment: Okay. Now I get it. 'Visible' refers to 'accessible'. And `public` makes it accessible from anywhere. `open` allows inheritance of a class. Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

`class A { ... }` in Java is equal to `open class A { ... }` in Kotlin.
`final class B { ... }` in Java is equal to `class B { ...}` in Kotlin.

It is not related with `public`.

In Kotlin, everything without access modifiers is `public` by default. You can explicitly say `public` in the definition, but it is not necessary in Kotlin.

So,

```
public class A { ... }
```

and

```
class A { ... }
```

are the same in Kotlin.

Comment: If so, what exactly is the use of making a class `public`? If you use `open`, you can inherit the class. What is the main purpose of making a class `public`?

Comment: I think it's like a semicolon in Kotlin. They exist for Java people.

Answer (score 15):

I put here just for my memo, maybe useful for someone else :

**open** class in kotlin means that a class can be inherited because by default they are not:

```
 class Car{....}
 class Supercar:Car{....} : // give an error

 open Car2{....}
 class Supercar:Car2{....} : // ok
```

**public** class in Java is about the visibility of class (nothing to do with inheritance : unless a class in java is final, it can be inherited by default).
In kotlin all the class are public by default.

**open** method in kotlin means that the method can be overridden, because by default they are not.
Instead in Java all the methods can be overridden by default

**The method of an open** class cannot be overridden by default as usual (doesn't matter if the class is open), they must be declared that they can be overridden :

```
 open class Car{
    fun steering{...}
 }
 class Supercar:Car{
    override fun steering {...}  // give an error
 } 

 open class Car2{
    open fun steering{...}
 }
 class Supercar:Car2{
    override fun steering {...}  // ok
 }
```

for more details : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Answer (score 7):

**public**: public keyword in Kotlin is similar to java it is use to make the visibility of classes, methods, variables to access from anywhere.

**open**: In Kotlin all classes, functions, and variables are by defaults final, and by inheritance property, we cannot inherit the property of final classes, final functions, and data members. So we use the open keyword before the class or function or variable to make inheritable that.

Comment: This is wrong, you still can inherit a visible non-`open` member however you cannot override it.

Comment: Please visit below link of Kotlin official website to clear your doubt.  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20Kotlin%20classes%20are%20final%20%E2%80%93%20they%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20inherited.%20To%20make%20a%20class%20inheritable%2C%20mark%20it%20with%20the%20open%20keyword%3A

Comment: Also when we make the parent class 'abstract' it will be inheritable.

Comment: @karakays's comment is perhaps pedantic, but correct. A subclass always *inherits* all the parent class's members - that is, all methods and properties that exists on the parent class will also exist on the subclass. Applying the `open` modifier to class members determines whether they are *overridable*, not whether they are *inheritable*. The docs you link to in your reply to him corroborate his point.

Answer (score 4):

open is opposite to Final in java.
If the class is not 'open', it can't be inherited.

```
class First{}
class Second:First(){}  // Not allowed. Since 'First' is Final(as in Java) by default. Unless marked "open" it can't be inherited
```

Don't get confused with open and public. public is a visibility modifier

```
class Third{}  // By default this is public
private class Fourth{}
class Fifth{
    val third = Third() // No issues
    val fourth = Fourth() // Can't access because Fourth is private
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All `classes`, `methods`, and `members` are `public` by default BUT not `open`

Keyword `open` in kotlin means "Open for Extension"

means if you want any class to be `inherited` by any subclass or `method` to be overriden in subclasses you have to mark as `open` otherwise you will get compile time error

NOTE: `abstract` classes or methods are `open` by default you do not need to add explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

**OPEN VS FINAL VS PUBLIC**

OPEN :

1. child class can access this because they are inherited by its parent.
2. In Kotlin you need to add 'open' keyword unlike java whose all classes are 'open' by default
   Example :

> 1. Kotlin : open class A () {}
> 2. Java : class A () {}

FINAL :

1. child class can't access or inherit.
2. In JAVA you need to add 'final' keyword unlike kotlin whose all classes are 'final' by default
   Example :

> 1. Kotlin : class A () {}
> 2. Java : final class A () {}

PUBLIC : Any class whether its inherited or not can access its data or methods.

Example in Kotlin :

```
//Final
class DemoA() {
    
    protected fun Method() {

    }

}

class DemoB() : DemoA {
    Method() // can't access
}

//OPEN
open class DemoA() {
    
    protected fun Method() {

    }

}

class DemoB() : DemoA {
    Method() // can access
}

//Public
class DemoA() {

    fun Method() {

    }

}

class DemoB()  {
    val a = DemoA()
    a.Method() // can access
}
```

Example in Java :

```
//FINAL
final class DemoA() {
    protected void name() {
        
    }
}

class DemoB() extends DemoA {
    name(); // Can't access
}

//Open
class DemoA() {
    protected void name() {
        
    }
}

class DemoB() extends DemoA {
    name(); // Can access
}

//Public
class DemoA() {
    void name() {
        
    }
}

class DemoB(){
    DemoA a = new DemoA()
    a.name(); // Can access
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Summarized answer (Kotlin)

- The defaults of declarations of classes, methods, and properties are
  **(public + final)**. **final** prevents any inheritance attempts.
- In order to be able to **extend** a **class**, you must mark the
  **parent** class with the **open** keyword.
- In order to be able to **override** the **methods** or **properties**, you must
  mark them in the **parent** class with the **open** keyword, in addition to
  marking the **overriding** method or parameter with the **override** keyword.
- **public** is just encapsulation, it affects the **visibility** of classes/ methods. Public will make them visible everywhere.

[Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-rules)