# what is `open` keyword for fields in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin `open` is the same as not `final` in Java for classes and methods.

What does `open` give me in the following class for the field marked as `open`?

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity() : Persistable<Long> {
     open var id: Long? = null
}
```

**updated**
this is not duplicate of [What is the difference between 'open' and 'public' in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024200/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-public-in-kotlin)

I am interested in `open` keyword for properties

**updated**

`open` class can be inherited.
`open` fun can be overridden
`val` property is `final` field in java

what about `open` property?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 it is not duplicate I am curious about `open` keyword for fields

Comment: Just an observation - I know nothing of Kotlin, so I am abstaining from voting. But, if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating its usage with properties (don't just add "updated" to the original question, change the *whole* question to specifically be about open vs non-open properties), this *might* be reopened because the other question does not seem to address it. Just be sure to keep the "this is not a dupe" text and link in the question, too.

Comment: The open keyword for a field allows the field visibility/content to be changed later on, and still keeping the same name: ```open class Container {
         protected open val fieldA: String = "Some value"
       }
       class DerivedContainer : Container() {
         public override val fieldA: String = "Something else"
       }
```

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of __difference between open and public__ ?

Comment: I feel it's really important to mention here that there is no such thing as "fields" in Kotlin. Kotlin has **properties**. This is a getter method for **val**s and a getter and a setter methods for **var**s defined in a class. Even though they have a backing *field* under the hood, we shouldn't bother about it. Now that this is mentioned, the "open" keyword for **properties** should make much more sense, since it simply states that the generated get/set methods won't be final and will be open for overriding.

Comment: You can read this blog for more information regarding open keyword
https://www.android4dev.com/what-is-open-class-in-android-kotlin/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you said, the `open` keyword allows you to override classes, when used in the class declaration. Accordingly, declaring a property as `open`, allows subclasses to override the property itself (e.g., redefine getter/setter). That keyword is required since in Kotlin everything is "`final`" by default, meaning that you can't `override` it (something similar to C#, if you have experience with that).

Note that your class is implicitly declared as `open` since it is `abstract`, hence you cannot create an instance of that class directly.

Comment: I didn't get how is the class implicitly declared as open since it is abstract thing...

Comment: @kevz `abstract` means you can't create an instance of that class but you must subclass it first. Because of that, marking a class as `abstract` means the class is also `open` (otherwise you wouldn't be able to subclass it). Example: `abstract class Shape` can't be directly instantiated, but you can create and instantiate subclasses (e.g. `Triangle`, `Rectangle`, ...)

Answer (score 24):

**final method in Java**: A method that cannot be overridden.

**final class in Java**: A class that cannot be extended.

Open classes and methods in Kotlin are equivalent to the opposite of final in Java, an open method is overridable and an open class is extendable in Kotlin.

Comment: An open property must be a non-final field in Java

Comment: It might be less confusing to define `open` without using a reference to java, especially since your answer seems to ignore the subtleties of this reserved word.